# unable to retrieve multiple values in dialogue list from a column marked as "show multiple values as separate entries" in lotus

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotus

[image: a view image]

I have a column which has been marked as "show multiple values as separated value".
When trying to get its column value using

```
@DbColumn("Notes":"NoCache";@Subset(@DbName;1):@Subset(@DbName;-1);"View_name";1)
```

it only returns the first value of the field, not all.

Comment: Can you give some screenshots of the column properties and the full @dbcolumn formula?

Comment: please check, edited the formula

Comment: properties i used in column are sort "Ascending",and "Show multiple values as separate entry"

Comment: This should work exactly like this...

Comment: but its not working

Comment: Is the field in the document marked as multi-value? Has it *always* been marked as multi-value? If not, have you refreshed the documents?

Comment: it is multi-value field. I refreshed the document as well.

Comment: And if you open the view in the Notes client, do you see multiple entries?

Comment: i edited the post , plz check screen short

Comment: According to your screen shot you should receive "Export" and "Import" with your formula. Is this what you want? What do you get instead?

Comment: Only import (the first value)